# How to make a JS RegEx not to match if a certain string appear?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a RegEx in Javascript that does not match if a certain string appear. So I want to match this curly bracket `{` but only if in front of it is not the string `else`.

I am trying to do this `^ *[^else]* *{.*$` but in fact this doe not match if any character in `else`string appear, for example this does not match also this:

`erai {`
I want to match all the cases when `{` appear despite of this case `else {`.

Please could you help me. Here is my [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hY3eW1/1)

Comment: After looking at [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/hY3eW1/1), I'd suggest you [learn a bit more about regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead. This is supported by JavaScript:

```
(?!\s*else).+ *({).*$|
```

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hY3eW1/6)

---

JavaScript RegEx doesn't support ifs but we can use a trick for it to work:

```
(?!RegExp)
```

That's the first part, if `RegExp` *(which is a regex)* doesn't appear, then we do the code after that:

```
.+ *({).*$
```

That's the RegEx we run. Broken does, it is:

```
.+       Match anything
 *       Until 0 - unlimited spaces
({)      Capture the {
.*$      Match anything till the end
```

Now this won't work unless we add a `|` at the end, or an OR. This will trick it into working like an if statement

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/B6xt4weCPE_EZpkS)

Comment: thank for your help. But your DEMO also match this case `else {` . I dont want to match this...Please could you help me?

Comment: this also match `else {`...As I said I dont want to match this case.. The solution of @hwnd works for me

Comment: @orsina not sure what you mean, isn't that what the DEMO is doing?

Comment: I found a way to use your answer. I use `if` to check if the value returned from the match is undefined or not `if(typeof closeElseBl[1] !== 'undefined')` ...and than I continue with my function.. Thanks a lot and sory for my first comment, but I find later my solution

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is called [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support negative lookbehind

Comment: So @vihan is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: `^(?!.*\belse\s*{).*$`

Comment: @hwnd thanks. Your RegExp really function. `\b` stands for word boundary or not?  I can also use this RegEx with two words connected with `|` if I need. Thanks again for your help...